# How to read customer managed encrypted file stored in cloud storage from google cloud dataflow?

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

Google Customer Managed Encryption (CMEK) stored in google cloud storage can't be accessed directly by dataflow. How such avro encoded files be read in dataflow.

Thanks